# How to grab tcp at the same time and forward http to other tools on mitmproxy

Tags: python, mitmproxy, burp

How to grab tcp at the same time and forward http to other tools
I need client-> mitmproxy-> burp-> server
But i don't want to lose tcp traffic so what should i do
tcp_message (flow: tcp.TCPMessage) does not correctly forward http